# Variation Problem with Euler-Lagrange Differential Equation

Tags: calculus, calculus-of-variations

I'm just trying to understand that type of equations, and I can't solve this, kind of a simple minimization problem. Maybe someone can help me ? Here is my equation

$$\eqalign{
  & A(y(x)) = \int_{ - 1}^1 {{{\sqrt {1 + {{\left[ {y'(x)} \right]}^2}} } \over {y(x)}}dx}   \cr 
  & y( - 1) = 1  \cr 
  & y(1) = 1 \cr} $$

Thanks!

Comment: welcome to MSE. your problem is not clearly stated. :)

Comment: Try to edit your question. :) It is not clear that what is your problem. :)

Comment: @H. R. I presume he's trying to find a function y with the specified Dirichlet boundary, which minimises the functional A (presumably A stands for Action).

Comment: @Edgar What are you going to do with $A(y)$? Minimize it maybe?

Comment: @A.G. Yes. I'm trying to minimize my function. Sorry for not clear question. I'm new here. V :)

Comment: @H.R. Yes, thank you :)

Comment: Use the Euler-Lagrange equation. With $L(y,y') = \sqrt{1+y'^2}/y$ the EL equation is $\frac{dL}{dy} - \frac{d}{dx}\frac{dL}{dy'} = 0$. This will give you a ODE that you need to solve.

Comment: @Winther I probably got the wrong ODE, maybe you could write next step from me ? Thx

Comment: Why don't you add what you have done to the question? This is standard practice here and it makes it easier to see where the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here the Lagrangian $L(t,y,v)=\frac{\sqrt{1+v^2}}{y}$ does not depend directly on the variable $t$, in this case is useful to apply the second formulation of Euler-Lagrange equation:

$$L(y(t),y'(t))-y'L_v(y(t),y'(t))=cost.$$

In your case it produces the following differential equation
$$y(t)\sqrt{1+y'(t)^2}=cost.=C$$

We can rewrite the previous equation in the form:

$$\pm \frac{y'(t)y(t)}{\sqrt{C^2-y(t)^2}}=1$$
and this is equivalent to
$$\pm\big(\sqrt{C^2-y(t)^2}\big)'=1.$$
Hence
$$\pm \sqrt{C^2-y(t)^2}=t+D$$
and finally squaring we get
$$C^2-y(t)^2=(t+D)^2.$$
Now just plug in the conditions $y(1)=y(-1)=1$ to get $D=0$ and $C^2=2$.

Comment: It applies if $\frac{dL}{dx}=0$ and that's the case here.

Comment: I meant the partial derivative respect to $x$ :$\frac{\partial L}{\partial x}=0$.

Comment: Sorry, I confused the variables. You are of course correct.

Comment: answer : "x^2+y^2=2" but i still have problems, probably in the first steps

Comment: $x^2+y(x)^2=2$ is indeed a solution of the differential equation I wrote.

Comment: @mrprottolo can you write full solution ? I'm trying to find my mistake. Thanks

Comment: @Edgar i added a scheme for a possible solution.

Comment: @mrprottolo Thank you very much !!

Comment: BTW there is one more solution to E-L equation that is missed here $y(x)\equiv 1$.

Comment: @A.G. i noticed that too, i guess it was lost on the denominator. Maybe I should check that is not the minimum.

Comment: @mrprottolo Before dividing by $\sqrt{C^2-y^2}$ one should check for solutions making it zero, i.e. $y=C$ in this case. It is typical when one does separating of the variables. It could be the optimal actually (perhaps not in this problem).

Comment: @A.G. I tried using wolframalpha, $y(t)=1$ seems to be optimal.

Comment: @mrprottolo $y(x)=1$ gives $2$ and the circle arc gives $2\ln(\sqrt{2}+1)\approx 1.76$. I did it kind of quick, so reservation for possible miscalculations.

Answer (score 2):

Just to make a complementing remark to @mrprottolo's solution.

It happens in some variational problems that the [Beltrami identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beltrami_identity) gives more complicated equations to solve than the canonical E-L equation. This problem is one of the examples. If we take the classical E-L we get after elementary simplifications that 
$$
y'(1+y'^2+yy'')=0,\quad y(-1)=y(1)=1.
$$
It gives one possibility $y'=0$ and another to be
$$
1+y'^2+yy''=1+(yy')'=1+\frac{1}{2}(y^2)''=0\qquad\Leftrightarrow\qquad (y^2)''=-2.
$$
Both DE's are very elementary (without square roots etc).